# Getting the null vaue in the textfield (fetching with the help of json decoding)

Tags: php, json

I am implementing a functionality in which users can update their profile. When user clicks on "update profile", a form and text fields are displayed with all their values returned to the user.

But I am unable to get the "Interest field", in which I encode the values to JSON and store it in array string. Now while retrieving it in the text field I use `json_decode`, which helps me to write the values in text field. But once user clicks on "save" and then clicks on "update", all values come null.

For more than one interest, text fields are dynamically added by the user. Here is the code that I wrote:

```
<div class="form-group" id="area_interest"> 
    <h4>Area of Interest</h4>
            <div style="display:inline-block">
                <? $interest = json_decode($model->profile->interest,true) ? : [];

                foreach($interest as $area_int) {  ?>
                        <label>Enter Interest:</label>
                        <input name="$area_int" type="text" value="<?= $area_int ?>"/>                        
                <? } 
                <div style="display:inline-block">
                    <input type="button" value="Add More Interest" onClick="addTextArea();">
                </div>

            </div>
</div>
```

Function for adding more textbox dynamically:

```
function addTextArea(){
var div = document.getElementById('interests');

  div.innerHTML += "<label>Enter Interest</label>"
  div.innerHTML += '<?php echo $model->form->textBoxFor("interests[]"); ?> ';
  div.innerHTML += "\n<br />";
}
```

The code in the function is:

```
$interests = isset($_POST['interests']) ? $_POST['interests']: [];
$_POST['interests'] = json_encode($interests);
```

What should I write in name ?
I don't know where I missed some important point. Help would be greatly appreciated. TIA.

Comment: You are using `name="$area_int"`. Are you sure about it?

Comment: Doesn't it raise error `<? $interest = json_decode($model->profile->interest,true) ? : [];`? You are not providing second operand to conditional operator.

Comment: No I didn't get any error for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input name="$area_int" type="text" value="<?= $area_int ?>"/>
```

I think the name is the issue, if in the function u are accessing the `$_POST['$area_int']` value it should work, but if u are accesing `$_POST['area_int']` , that value will not be found.

Hope my answer helps u.

-----All this after the comments-----

I see the method `$model->form->textBoxFor("interests[]")` im gessing that method allows u you to create a new input, so i guess it `echo` a javascript function that allows that, the name if the input is `interests[]`

In the function on your controller you sould get it as `$_POST['interests']`, that will contain all the `interests` u added in the form, so **how to get those values?**

When the name of an input is `nameOfTheInput[]` php accept those inputs as an array, so when u are accessing `$_POST['interests']`, u are getting

```
array (
        0 => 'this is my first NEW interest', 
        1 => 'this is my second NEW inetrest',
        ....
        n => 'this is my n NEW interest'
  );
```

After that u should process the values.

Hope my answer helps u.
But try to be especifics on how your code is working.

Comment: Added the code in the question that I have written in function in controller file.

Comment: unless via your function ´addTextArea();´ u are sending to the controller the value of the array there is no way `$_POST['interest]` is defined.

Comment: Ohh I see, I think that's the problem, check the edited question again to see the ´addTextArea()´ function. Can you tell me where and what should I change to make it work.?